# Android OpenGL es weird buggy black squares on the screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering

I'm making an OpenGL es 3.0 app for android, and recently, I started to see weird black squares on my screen:

[image: image of black square bugs]

I have a fairly low-spec phone, and I suspect it is related to how much I ask of the GPU.

I have a deferred rendering pipeline with several post-processing effects enabled. I render the UI after the 3D and the post-processing passes.

What do these black squares mean, why are they there, can I avoid them and if so how?

Comment: In my experience that's usually related to memory issues - you could sometimes see it in web browsers when phones had a lot less memory, parts of the rendered surface would be "missing". If you want to investigate properly you could have a poke around here: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics but I'd look at making sure you're being careful about how much memory you're using, if you're using the appropriate texture sizes and compression, etc

Comment: I've occasionally seen artifacts like that with bloom/blur post-processing style effects. They can be caused by NaNs or Infinities produced by one shader getting spread about by the blur kernel. They can be tricky to track down - disabling parts of your scene can help isolate it, then look for possible sources of NaNs or Infinities - common ones are divide-by-zero, and pow(x,y) when x might be negative (it's not a bad idea to change all your pows to pow(max(0.0, x), y);)